# Org export "invalid function" error

Tags: org-export, functions, sexp

This is my `export.el`:

```
(require 'ox-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(

("org-notes"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
 :auto-preamble nil
 :html-preamble "<div id=\"navbar\"> <ul>
  <li><a href=\"index.html\">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"blog.html\">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"/iletisim.html\">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"/hakkinda.html\">About</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</div>
"
 )

("org-static"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
 )

("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))

       ;; ... add all the components here (see below)...

      ))
```

When I do `C-x C-e at the end of ”org-notes” I get this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function "org-notes")
  ("org-notes" :base-directory "~/org/" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble nil :html-preamble "<div id=\"navbar\"> <ul>\n  <li><a href=\"index.html\">...")
  eval(("org-notes" :base-directory "~/org/" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble nil :html-preamble "<div id=\"navbar\"> <ul>\n  <li><a href=\"index.html\">...") nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

When I evaluate with `C-x C-e` with curser at the end of the buffer I don’t get any error messages.

The last change I made to `export.el` was to change titles in `:html-preamble`. Export to HTML works fine except that some pages still have the old titles. I did a hard refresh on the browser but nothing changed.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: @jagrg When I make these changes I get the following errors: `eval: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-html-publish-to-html` and 
`eval: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-publish-attachment`

Comment: You're missing a quote before `org-html-publish-to-html` and `org-publish-attachment`.

Comment: Do you mean double quotes like this `"org-html-publish-to-html"` ?

Comment: Like this: `'org-html-publish-to-html`.

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong: if you choose to evaluate an arbitrary Lisp expression with `C-x C-e`, you probably will get an error.

Try this in a buffer: type `("foo" "bar")`, and then say `C-x C-e` at the end. You will get `invalid-function "foo"`. Does that mean something is wrong with the expression? No - you chose to evaluate a Lisp expression, a list in this case, and the evaluator will assume that the `car` of the list is a function and try to apply the function to the arguments. So it will try to call the function `"foo"` with an argument of `"bar"`. Since `"foo"` is not a function (it's a string), you get the error.

What is wrong is that you tried to evaluate that Lisp expression as a *function application*. But that expression is not meant to be a function application: it's just data. The fact that Lisp programs and data look the same does not mean that they are interchangeable.

In your case, `("org-notes" ....)` is *not* meant to be a function application, so evaluating it leads to an `invalid-function` error, just as in the `("foo" "bar")` case above. OTOH, doing `C-x C-e` at the end of the buffer does work: it evaluates the function[1] `setq` which assigns to the symbol that is its first argument, the value that is its second argument.

---

[1] `setq` is really a `special form`, not a `function`, because it treats its first argument specially, but that is not germane to the question. See [Function Forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Forms.html) and [Special Forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Forms.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.